# Adding CSS style in Table using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

On http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/poker-players.html - AJAX loads JSON data into a table and Im trying to add some classes to display background-color on only two  tags seperately and center the texts, but it didnt work for me and I removed it. I need the table to look like this - http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/img/table-example.jpg

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("js/dataPokerPlayers.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, data){
            $(".tableData tbody").append("<tr><td>" + data.rank + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td>" + data.earnings + "</td><td>" + data.points + "</td><td>" + data.totalearnings + "</td></tr>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hold on a second, you are developing a webpage for a pokerOnline but you don't know how to add a css selector to a <td> nor to text-align:center ???

Comment: Yes, I said I tried to add "class="centertext" to center the texts, but it didnt work in javascript. Evan put class=\"center\" for me, that is fairly new to me to put two \s. in <td> By the way, its not an online game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in `class="center"` to the `<td>` elements that you want to be centered and then use a CSS selector to style those `td`'s with the `center` class name.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("js/dataPokerPlayers.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, data){
            $(".tableData tbody").append("<tr><td>" + data.rank + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td class=\"center\">" + data.earnings + "</td><td class=\"center\">" + data.points + "</td><td>" + data.totalearnings + "</td></tr>");
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're also trying to change the background color of alternating rows. You can do you with this css: `.tableData tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #000000; }`

Comment: Thank you Evan! mchail that is what I need, but it didnt work for me.

Comment: and that will close the question? I still have one more to go to fix the alernating row background-color nth-child(even) that didnt work for me

Comment: @Christian That wasn't part of the original question. Honestly, you should close this one and open up another one with the background colors. However, look up "zebra table layout" and you'll find your answer :)